# WinForm chart issue

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to create a `chart` based on a `dataTable`. The table contains only two columns, names and count:

```
+-------+-------+
| names | count |
+-------+-------+
| name1 | 650   |
+-------+-------+
| name2 | 0     |
+-------+-------+
| name3 | 211   |
+-------+-------+
| name4 | 50    |
+-------+-------+
```

I want the `Y axis` to be the `count`. I want a column to be generated for each `name` and labelled with the actual names.

This is what I tried:

```
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][1]) > max) max = Convert.ToInt32(max.Rows[i][1]);
}
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area");
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = max;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = max/ 10;

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    chart1.Series.Add(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());
}
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(table.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][1]));
}
```

And this is what I get, which is not quite what I expected:
[image]

Comment: You are adding many series but I guess you only want one! Also note that there are predefined CAs and Series; make sure to clear them to keep full control.

Comment: I cleared everything. It's a totally empty chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    chart1.Series.Add(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());
}
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(table.Rows[i][0].ToString(),  
                                  Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][1]));
}
```

to this:

```
Series S = chart1.Series.Add("names");

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    S.Points.AddXY(table.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][1]));
}
```

Your original code added one series for each row and one datapoint to each series. This made the chart place them all beside each other and display their sole point, each with the unique series color..

The new code creates only one series and adds all datapoints to its Points collection.